# SQL Developer ISA hierarchy to relation model

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have logical model with ISA hierarchi("Subtree generation" set to "Table for each entity"). I engineer it to relation model and when I want generate create script using "Generate DDL" I get these 2 same errors:

> --  ERROR: No Discriminator Column found in Arc FKArc_1 - constraint trigger for Arc cannot be generated
>
> --  ERROR: No Discriminator Column found in Arc FKArc_1 - constraint trigger for Arc cannot be generated

I am new to databases and SQL Dev(I have version 4.0.3) and I have no idea how to solve this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Discriminator Column and Values in your Arc property.

1. Double-click on the arc.
2. Set the Discriminator Column using the drop-down menu.
3. Click on the Foreign Keys tab.
4. The member FKs should be listed. Make sure you enter a Discriminator value for each.

HTH!